# How to detect moveCamera is finished on the Google map service?

Tags: android, dictionary, callback

I want to take a snapshot when moveCamera is finished.

I used both onCamerachange() and onMapLoaded() functions to Googlemap object,

But this callback handler's timing is not fit on my intention.

I want to move camera to what I want, and when loading map is finished, want to take a screnshot.

Who do you guys know about how can I do?

Thank you.

====================================================

+MYSOLUTION

Actually, I want to implement tilesloaded() call back function that is supported on the google map API of the javascript. 
But, as a result, there is no function which is completely accomplished that function.

OnMapLoaded() callback function is just invoked once when the map is loaded first.

OnCameraChanged() or OnCancallableCallback is invoked before all the tiles are loaded.

So I implemented like below source code

```
...
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 10), this);
...
    @Override
public void onFinish() {
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
..
    @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mMap = googleMap;// Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    mMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(this);
}
```

Now, when the camera is moved, onMapLoaded() is always invoked.

Thank you everybody.

Answer (score 42):

You can implement this:

```
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(16), 3000, new GoogleMap.CancelableCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                //Here you can take the snapshot or whatever you want
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

            }
        });
```

The most detailed form of this method, GoogleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate, duration, callback), offers three arguments:

### **cameraUpdate**

The CameraUpdate describing where to move the camera.
callback
An object that implements GoogleMap.CancellableCallback. This generalized interface for handling tasks defines two methods `onCancel()` and `onFinished()`. For animation, the methods are called in the following circumstances:

### **onFinish()**

Invoked if the animation goes to completion without interruption.

### **onCancel()**

Invoked if the animation is interrupted by calling stopAnimation() or starting a new camera movement.

Alternatively, this can also occur if you call GoogleMap.stopAnimation().

Source: [Google Maps Android API Guides](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/views)

Comment: Thanks @Brandon Zamudio. But I think your solution is just about Camera. When I tested, they invoked when the camera move finished, but the map is not drawn already..

Comment: You just have to do a previous validation to make sure that the map is already showing

Answer (score 0):

So you are definitely in the right area by using the onCameraChange() and onMapLoaded() callback. The best way to handle this would be to handle your screenshot in the onMapLoaded() function.
Also, remember to use the newest libraries, and the support libraries when instantiating your map fragment. This is **very** important.

So:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //...All of the other important things you have here

    //Instantiate the map object using the support library
    map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
        .getMap();

    map.getMapAsync(this);

    //Add the callback to your map object
    map.setOnMapLoadedCallback(this);

}

@Override
public void onMapLoaded(){
    //Perform screenshot here
}
```

**EDIT**
Here is code for a handler, complete with comments.

```
@Override
public void onCameraChange(){

    //Constant for our time. I would put this below your class declaration
    private static final int DELAY_TIME_IN_MILLI = 3000;

    //Here is the handler for waiting
    mMap.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                //This function runs after the time allotted below 
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    //Call your screenshot function here
                    takeScreenShot();
                }
            },DELAY_TIME_IN_MILLI);            //Our delay
}
```

Comment: I tried before your solution, but Map load callback function is not invoked after move camera. I don't know why exactly Thanks @Jason Cromer

Comment: onMapLoadedCallback is called just once on OnCreate()

Comment: Although this way is a bit of a hack, you could always put a handler at the end of your onCameraChange() function, and have it wait a certain amount of seconds before taking the screenshot. For example, have the handler wait 3 seconds, which is more than enough time for the map to load in **most** situations.
Although this is a bit of a hack, it will probably get your job done.

Comment: Yes, exactly. But I don't know more optimized things. According to bug report, it is not solved yet. Do you have any good solution? Thanks a lot for your replies.

Comment: Just do what I mentioned in the comment above. Put a handler in your onCameraChange() function that will wait for about 3 seconds, then call the function that will take the screenshot. I will edit my response above to add the code for a handler.